# What's the best way of implementing multiple activities?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have a few activities in my app, and I define them like this:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".DetailsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".ZoomActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Something.FullScreen"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".RadioActivity"
            android:label="@string/radio"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

DetailsActivity and ZoomActivity are activities started after tapping on an item in RecyclerView, and they just show details of an item.

RadioActivity is an activity bound to service.

SettingsActivity is just an ordinary android preferences activity.

I am not really certain if that's the best way to define multiple activities (I mean launchMode, clearTaskOnLaunch and excludeFromRecents).

Should I leave it as is, or maybe change my approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine.

If you're afraid of having to declare many activities, it's likely that you're unnecessarily creating new subclasses of activities you can reuse. Bear in mind that you can easily pass data into an activity through the Intent's Bundle.

It's difficult to say if the flags you're providing for each activity necessarily make sense, but if you want the application to close when the user backs out of one activity, and itself have no history in the back stack, then this is will accomplish that task.